# How to customize date/time picker in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I can create such dialog using `AlertDialog` library, however I want to use same kind of input for height and weight. Creating a custom dialog will need implementing many things such as 'sliding to change the value'. How should I edit the values in existing picker?

[image: Date Picker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DatePickerDialog` dialog contains three [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) widgets under the hood.

All you have to do is create an `AlertDialog` with custom view containing a single `NumberPicker` widget. The display and sliding is provided by the `NumberPicker` widget. You can set min value, max value, default value etc...

Comment: Right! Wasn't aware of NumberPicker widget. Thanks

Comment: @hXT1022 my pleasure.